# Import nested partitioned parquet file into Big Query table

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have parquet files in cloud storage which are nested partitioned on year -> month ->day. I want this file to be ingested into Big query table. How do I do this? I am new to GCP.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I’ve been fighting with this issue recently too.

If you’re trying to do this programatically, through CLI or with a BigQuery client or something, [take a look at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77274998/2597237).  It shows how to set up your Table Definition as JSON.

To create partitions in the UI is pretty easy after you get the `Source URI prefix` and the `Source file(s) URI pattern` correct.
Your bucket also needs to have the correct folder structure and the files should have the same schema.

Your bucket folder structure should be something like this

`gs://bucketName[/any/level/of/nesting]/<tableName>/<partition>=<val>[/other partitions if needed]/<file name>`

1. Create a table under the dataset you want to use
2. For the `Source File(s) URI`, use `bucketName`, all the nesting if you have any, and the `tableName`.  If your bucket is called `raw_data` and you have 2 nested folders called `news` and `weather` and your paritioned table is called `ingest` and your partition is called `dt`, your `File Source URI pattern` would be `raw_data/news/weather/ingest/*.parquet`
3. Click the `Source Data Partitioning` checkbox
4. For the `Source URI prefix` parameter, you can either put the partition part in the `Source URI prefix` or do it in a later step.  To put it in the URI prefix, you would enter your prefix in the UI like this `gs://raw_data/news/weather/station_reports/{dt:DATE}`.  If you want to set up the partition later, just leave off the `{dt:DATE} piece for now—I suggest leaving it off because you can be more explicit if you set it up in step 5 and it seems to work better for me.
5. If you left off the `{dt:DATE}` piece in step 4, click the `Provide my own` option, in the `Partition Inference Mode` section.  You should add 1 partition called `dt` or whatever else you like and it should be a `DATE` type.  If you want to call your partition something else, just make sure it’s not one of Google’s reserved keywords like `type` and make sure it isn’t one of the columns in your file.

You can mimic that using the CLI, if that’s how you want to create your table.
I’m trying to use Composer (Airflow) and still haven’t had luck getting it to work with the `BigQueryCreateExternalTableOperator` operator but I found [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75280828/google-composer-creation-of-partitioned-external-tables) this morning that I’ll test out.

This is the link where I found [instructions to go from](https://sourabhsjain.medium.com/querying-externally-partitioned-data-in-bigquery-97873fd157ac).

Here’s a picture of what it might look like, when you do it through the UI.
[image: A picture showing source file URI pattern and file prefix, when you do it through the UI]

Answer (score -1):

You can use Cloud Shell in your GCP project and execute the following command:

```sh
bq load \
--source_format=PARQUET \
dataset.table \
"gs://mybucket/my_file.parquet"
```

Replacing the values with your own dataset, table and Cloud Storage URI path of your parquet file.

Alternatively, and probably simpler, you can also use the [web console](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-parquet#loading_parquet_data_into_a_new_table) to load your parquet file into BigQuery.

Comment: This answer doesn’t address the question of partitioned data.