# How to create a bigquery external table with custom partitions

Tags: google-bigquery

I would like to create a biggqury external table for data stored in:

```
gs://mybucket/market/US/v1/part-001.avro
gs://mybucket/market/US/v2/part-001.avro
...
gs://mybucket/market/CA/v1/part-001.avro
gs://mybucket/market/CA/v2/part-001.avro
...
```

With a table definition file

```
{
  "avroOptions": {
    "useAvroLogicalTypes": true
  },
  "hivePartitioningOptions": {
    "mode": "CUSTOM",
    "sourceUriPrefix": "gs://mybucket/market/{cc:STRING}/{version:STRING}"
  },
  "sourceFormat": "AVRO",
  "sourceUris": [
    "gs://mybucket/market/*/*/*.avro"
  ]
}
```

and a schema file:

```
[
  {
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "name": "id",
    "type": "STRING"
  },
  {
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "name": "name",
    "type": "STRING"
  },
  ...
```

The table is created with command:

```
bq mk --external_table_definition=tabledef.json ds.mytable schema.json
```

But when trying to query the table, following error is reported

```
Failed to expand table ds.mytable with file pattern gs://mybucket/market/*/*/*.avro: matched no files. File: gs://mybucket/market/*/*/*.avro
```

I also tried many variations as below, but none of them worked.

```
 gs://mybucket/market/*
 gs://mybucket/market/**.avro
 gs://mybucket/market/**/*.avro
```

Can anyone see what the problem might be?

Thanks

Comment: did you try auto mode instead of custom on hive partitioning? also, for sourceUri gs://mybucket/market/* this should be enough no? I always try to follow this pattern on gcs sth like gs://mybucket/market/cc=US/version=v1

Comment: AUTO did not work because the data does not following hive-partition pattern and it is not for me to change it. 

I followed instruction here: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/hive-partitioned-queries-gcs#providing_a_custom_partition_key_schema

The problem with "gs://mybucket/market/*" is it also matches path so I got error like:

Incompatible partition schemas. Expected schema ([cc:TYPE_STRING, version:TYPE_STRING]) has 2 columns. Observed schema ([]) has 0 columns. File: US/v1

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you’re pretty close but I saw a few things that I think will take you passed the finish line:

1. [From this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tables#HivePartitioningOptions), in order to use Hive partitioning, which is what will let you adjust your partitions based on file path, your bucket’s path looks like this `gs://mybucket/market/US/v1/part-001.avro` but it should be `gs://mybucket/market/cc=US/version=v1/part-001.avro`
2. The `externalDataConfiguration.sourceUris` in your table definition should be `gs://mybucket/market*.avro`.  This is where you use the glob path to find ALL files.  Remeber that this is going to be like a quazi-regex string search against all your files in your bucket; It’s not like a linux file system search, where you have to look through nested folders.
3. Your `externalDataConfiguration.hivePartitioningOptions.sourceUriPrefix` should look like `gs://mybucket/{cc:STRING}/{version:STRING}`.  This tells BigQuery to only consider files with this string prefix in their Object Name (bucket file path).

So, bringing it all together, make your table definition include these parts

```
{
    …,
    “externalDataConfiguration”: {
        …,
        “sourceUris”: [
            "gs://mybucket/market*.avro"
        ],
        …,
        "hivePartitioningOptions": {
            "mode": 'CUSTOM',
            "sourceUriPrefix": "gs://mybucket/{cc:STRING}/{version:STRING}",
            …
        },
        …,
    }
}
```

[This is the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tables#TableSchema) that I used to get my external, parquet based tables with Hive partitions working, which sounds like what you’re doing with avro files.

I hope that helps someone out there.  I was stuck on this for a few days.