# Google Composer - Creation of partitioned External tables

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-composer

I am trying to create an External table on top of Google Cloud Storage bucket through Composer DAG. My upstream provides me partitioned parquet files based on specific country. So, I would like to create an external table with Source Data partitioning enabled.

**Sample GCS Path** - gs://my-gs-bucket/folder1/subfolder/country=US/ (has multiple parquet files)

While creating the external table through console. Below are the options provided

**Source:**

*Create table from -> Google Cloud Storage*

*Select file from GCS bucket or use a URI pattern -> gs://my-gs-bucket/folder1/subfolder/country**

*File Format -> Parquet*

*Source Data Partitioning - Enabled*

*Select Source URI Prefix - gs://my-gs-bucket/folder1/subfolder*

I would like to do this through Composer DAG. I was able to create an External table on the GCS files using BigQueryCreateExternalTableOperator but without Source Data Partitioning. Any idea how do we enable `Source Data Partitioning` and `Select Source URI Prefix` through DAG.

Answer (score 1):

There is no parameter to create partitioned External tables in [BigQueryCreateExternalTableOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.12/_api/airflow/contrib/operators/bigquery_operator/index.html#airflow.contrib.operators.bigquery_operator.BigQueryCreateExternalTableOperator).

For your requirement to create Partitioned table you can consider below sample code to run dag’s which uses `BigQueryCreateEmptyDatasetOperator` and [`BigQueryCreateEmptyTableOperator`](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.12/_api/airflow/contrib/operators/bigquery_operator/index.html#airflow.contrib.operators.bigquery_operator.BigQueryCreateEmptyTableOperator) to create dataset and partitioned table with the time_partitioning parameter in BigQuery.

```
import os
import time
import datetime
from datetime import datetime, date, time, timedelta

from airflow import models
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.operators.bigquery import (
    BigQueryCreateEmptyDatasetOperator,
    BigQueryCreateEmptyTableOperator,
)

from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago

PROJECT_ID = os.environ.get("GCP_PROJECT_ID", "your-project-id")
DATASET_NAME = os.environ.get("GCP_BIGQUERY_DATASET_NAME", "testdataset")

TABLE_NAME = "partitioned_table"

SCHEMA = [
    {"name": "value", "type": "INTEGER", "mode": "REQUIRED"},
    {"name": "ds", "type": "DATE", "mode": "NULLABLE"},
]

dag_id = "example_bigquery"


with models.DAG(
    dag_id,
    schedule_interval="@hourly",  # Override to match your needs
    start_date=days_ago(1),
    tags=["example"],
    user_defined_macros={"DATASET": DATASET_NAME, "TABLE": TABLE_NAME},
    default_args={"project_id": PROJECT_ID},
) as dag_with_locations:
    create_dataset = BigQueryCreateEmptyDatasetOperator(
        task_id="create-dataset", dataset_id=DATASET_NAME, project_id=PROJECT_ID
    )
    create_table = BigQueryCreateEmptyTableOperator(
        task_id="create_table",
        dataset_id=DATASET_NAME,
        table_id=TABLE_NAME,
        schema_fields=SCHEMA,
        time_partitioning={
            "type": "DAY",
            "field": "ds",
        },
    )
    
    create_dataset >> create_table
```

You can also use schema from GCS, Example (with schema JSON in GCS):

```
CreateTable = BigQueryCreateEmptyTableOperator(
    task_id='BigQueryCreateEmptyTableOperator_task',
    dataset_id='ODS',
    table_id='Employees',
    project_id='internal-gcp-project',
    gcs_schema_object='gs://schema-bucket/employee_schema.json',
    bigquery_conn_id='airflow-service-account',
    google_cloud_storage_conn_id='airflow-service-account'
)
```

You can refer to this [stack link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69651569/how-to-create-external-table-in-google-big-query-for-parquet-file-to-run-in-airf/69655200#69655200) to create external table for Parquet file using `BigQueryCreateExternalTableOperator`.